# Minimize the Max Distance

Tags: python-3.x, graph, networkx

I am trying to use NetworkX to minimize the max distance in a path from s -> v: My idea is to to a for loop in a container of sorted edges.  I would append one edge at a time, checking to see if a path from s -> v has been created.  The nodes of my graph are (city, state) with distances between each as my edges.  My code is as follows. I cannot quite figure out what to do from here.  This is what I have so far to test that it only gives me back one path(the path of minimal weighted edge).  If I can get that back  I will then extract the minimum edge and display. The nodes and edge weights are all read in from a file. The user is then able to select cities by various attributes and edges in a range from one distance to another.  While I think my loop should break after the first path is found, it keeps going and displaying all paths.

```
def MinMaxDist(self):
    edges = []
    for edge in self.selected_edges:
        edges.append(edge)
    edges = sorted(edges)

    while True:
        print("Input source and targe nodes in the following format: Yankton, SD")
        source = str(input("Enter a source: "))
        target  = str(input("Enter a target: "))
        if not source:
            break
        try:
            for edge in edges:
                self.graph.add_path([edge])
                if nx.all_simple_paths(self.graph, source, target):                   
                    print(list(nx.all_simple_paths(self.graph, source, target)))               
                    break
         except:
             print("No path from %s to %s" (source, target))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only break out of the `for` loop, not the `while` loop when you iterate over edges. A `break` only breaks out one level. This is a time that you would want to `return` so that the entire function stops executing.

I also want to make one other change that's a little more Pythonic. Every `for`-loop has an `else`: code that's executed only if you don't break out of the loop.

```
def MinMaxDist(self):
    edges = sorted([edge for edge in self.selected_edges])

    while True:
        print("Input source and targe nodes in the following format: Yankton, SD")
        source = str(input("Enter a source: "))
        target  = str(input("Enter a target: "))
        if not source:
            break
        for edge in edges:
            self.graph.add_path([edge])
            if nx.has_path(self.graph, source, target):                   
                print(list(nx.all_simple_paths(self.graph, source, target)))               
                return
        else:
            print("No path from %s to %s" (source, target))
```

Comment: This works but still returns all paths.  I want to break as soon as the first path is found in a DFS search.  I'm trying to add one node at a time and see if there is a path. Because my graph is not directed I thought I could do it this way without a Binary Search. @aryamccarthy

Comment: 1) It's easier for users to help if you provide a [mcve]. This code operates inside a class I don't have, on data I don't see. 2) This code *returns* nothing, though it prints all paths because you *command it to* do exactly that: "all simple paths".

Comment: Arya, I have a GIS with cities and distances between cities.  In this method I have a graph which has been built from cities selected from various attributes, edges selected in a range of distances IE(100, 1000).  I want to minimize the max distsnce. I suspected adding one edge at a time, checking for a path each time, once one path is found, stop. Then return the  shortest edge along said path.  I know I may be able to binary search but I thought since my graph is not directed it could be achieved this way.  I hope this clarifies what I'm trying to do. Thank you for your help

Comment: To be clear—minimize the max distance? Or find a shortest-length path?

Comment: I want to minimize the max distance. I think I have figured out how to do it.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facility_location_problem) problem?

Comment: Yes, that problem. As if our gas tank could only travel along certain edges due to it's capacity.